# What is the relation between Apache web server and an Express (Node.js) server created for the backend of a website?

Tags: node.js, apache, express

If I understand it correctly, a web server (such as Apache) is software that is installed on a server (hardware) where files making up a website are stored, and handles requests to the server. When I purchase a hosting service from a hosting company, the web server software is normally already installed on the server (hardware) space on which I am renting, so I do not need to set up the web server software myself.

But when I upload to the server (hardware) the files of a website that has a backend written using Node.js (Express) for example, it also contains a file `server.js` with instructions how to handle GET, POST requests, etc. My question is, what is the difference in the purpose of the web server software (e.g. Apache) and the Express server I create for the backend of my website?

To better understand the logic, I am seeking answers to the following subquestions:

- Could the Express server be used on its own on the server hardware to handle all requests , replacing the web server like Apache altogether when the website is live on the Internet?
- In general, can a customer to make changes to the configuration of the web server software that comes with the server hardware provided by the host?
- Is it common to rent only server hardware and install/configure web server software there on one's own?

Express server (example):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully')
})

const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
});
```

Routes (example):

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Exercise = require('../models/exercise.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    Exercise.find()
        .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const duration = Number(req.body.duration);
    const date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

    const newExercise = new Exercise({username, description, duration, date});

    newExercise.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Exercise added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error ' + err))
});
```

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5k5M.png)

Comment: Hi, I think your question is a little out of scope for this site; take a look in relevant help [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)